# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression + Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /secure/projects/softilluminations/tasks/new
```

Getting above error on console of broswer.

[image]

My View side code is below

```
<%= link_to 'Create Task', new_secure_project_task_path(project), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block', data: {toggle: 'modal', disable_with: loader, remote: true } %>
```

On click of link, my modal popup open and functionality working fine but I don't know why syntax error comes in the console.

Thank You.

Comment: the error seems to be coming from a /tasks/new script, can you show that if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the script you're using. I believe the `/secure/projects/softilluminations/tasks/new` part is not surrounded by quotes, so it's considered an expression instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution...

```
<%= link_to 'Create Task', new_secure_project_task_path(project), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block', data: {disable_with: loader, remote: true } %>
```

The above is the correct. Actually i send ajax request so no need to add `toggle: 'modal'` in data. So that it's comming error.